# Converting numpy array to csv

Tags: arrays, csv, numpy

I am trying to convert a numpy array to a csv file using numpy.tofile however the array is too large for the csv and the csv only allows 255. How can I represent the full array in a csv?

Comment: To large for what?  What have you tried?  `np.savetxt`?

Comment: What are **your** requirements on the .csv or .txt file? Can you handle more columns?

Comment: You must precise *the csv only allows 255* .